# Drive-sdk Notification Push: How to Capture file changes for a certain folder and the user who made the change?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I would like to track changes of a specific folder and notify the users that have access to that folder. Especially, supposing that a group of people (users of my application) is working on a presentation (in the shared folder that my app is monitoring) I would like to capture every content change of the presentation and be able to say WHO modified the content and When.

The problems are:

1. when I use files().watch() to monitor a folder, I do not receive notifications when I modify the content of files that belong to that folder.
2. when I use changes().watch() to monitor the whole Drive.. I don't know how to tell 'Which user' is associated with each change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know a file has been changed you can look up the lastModifyingUserName from the Files.get() API

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files